# Response.Redirect not working Properly

Tags: asp.net

In my project i am check user Password experied or not and if experied then i redirect my page to change password page like this :

```
Sub VerifyPasswordResetNeeded()           
        Using db As New ContactConnectionFast
            Dim needPassChange = db.sp_UserPasswordResetNeed(CurrentUser.UserIdentity.UserID)
            If needPassChange(0) = "0" Then
                Response.Redirect("~/Secure/ChangePassword?reset=" + Encryption64.Encrypt(1), False)
            End If
        End Using          
    End Sub
```

this code i am checking in my master page .
but every time i got error message this message
[image]

please any one help me

Comment: I suspect what it's saying is that somehow the function you've shown is being executed when you're trying to reach the `ChangePassword` page - so you get in a redirect cycle where you keep trying to redirect back to exactly the same page.

Comment: actually after login i am checking this on my master if my sp return 0 then it's redirect to changepassword page.

Comment: Use the code on page instead of master page as page_load of page is called before the master page page_load

Comment: But does your `ChangePassword` page use the same master page?

Comment: yes masterpage are same

Comment: So you need to *prevent* this function from running if the page that the master is attached to is the `ChangePassword` page itself.

Answer (score 0):

i think redirecting to the page, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: Download fiddler (Free) from fiddlertool.com.Its easy tool for debugging. You can find why its causing problem while redirecting